# Hide/Unhide rows with VBA - multiple ranges

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I would like to hide/unhide rows with a click of a button. I have achieved this by using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)       

omrade = ActiveCell.Row + 4 & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + 37

   If Rows(omrade).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
     Rows(omrade).EntireRow.Hidden = False
   Else
     Rows(omrade).EntireRow.Hidden = True
   End If

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

It works if the cell is hyperlinked to the same cell (e.g. cell D5 is hyperlinked to D5 - this would toggle the visibility of row 9 - 42).

However, I have multiple links (>100) and I do not want to manually enter each Cell Reference in the hyperlink. I have tried making dynamic hyperlinks using the Hyperlink-formula, but then my VBA code won't run.

EDIT: Tried to clarify my issue.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking - if I click a hyperlink in cell `A1` should it toggle the visibility of rows 5 through 38? And if I click a hyperlink in cell `B2` should it toggle the visibility of rows 6 through 39? etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Dim rngHyperlinkCell As Range
    Dim omrade As Range

    Set rngHyperlinkCell = Target.Range
    Set omrade = rngHyperlinkCell.Parent.Rows(rngHyperlinkCell.Row + 4 & ":" & rngHyperlinkCell.Row + 37)

    If omrade.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        omrade.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        omrade.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This solves my problem! Just a small issue - how can I select the same cell I clicked after hiding/unhiding? If it is hyperlinked to A1 - the A1 cell is selected and I loose track of where in the sheet I am.

Comment: Solved it, added the following code:
ActiveSheet.Cells(rngHyperlinkCell.Row, rngHyperlinkCell.Column).Select

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Rows(omrade).EntireRow.Hidden = not Rows(omrade).EntireRow.Hidden
```

This would hide if visible and unhide if hidden.

Comment: This would simplify my code - however, I want to have multiple links to toggle a different set of rows depending on the location of that link. And, I do not want to manually enter the cell reference in each link.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering whether to post this as it's very similar to @Robin, and also uses the Hidden that @Vityata used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Dim subAddress As Range
    Dim omrade As Range

    'Set subAddress = Range(Target.subAddress) 'Where the link looks at.
    Set subAddress = Target.Range   'Where the link is.

    With subAddress.Parent
        Set omrade = .Range(.Cells(subAddress.Row + 4, 1), .Cells(subAddress.Row + 37, 1))

        omrade.EntireRow.Hidden = Not omrade.EntireRow.Hidden

    End With

End Sub
```